# Having hard time with VBA while creating sheets from other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this sort of code in VBA:

```
Sub itemselecter()

Dim Filename1 As String
Dim Sourcewb1 As Workbook
Dim Targetwb1 As Workbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False

If .Show = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
  Else
    Filename1 = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
  End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Sourcewb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename1)         'Open FIC data
Set Targetwb1 = ThisWorkbook

Targetwb1.Worksheets("Data").ClearContents
Sourcewb1.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=Targetwb.Sheets("Data").Cells
Sourcewb1.Close (False)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It gives me at the moment error 424, while trying to select the file from documents. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, check for comments inside the code where I've made modifications.

If you would have added `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, then the second error wouldn't have occurred (where you mixed-up `Targetwb` with `Targetwb1`).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub itemselecter()

Dim Filename1 As String
Dim Sourcewb1 As Workbook
Dim Targetwb1 As Workbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Filename1 = .SelectedItems(1)
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Sourcewb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename1)         'Open FIC data
Set Targetwb1 = ThisWorkbook

Targetwb1.Worksheets("Data").Cells.ClearContents '<-- added .Cells to clear the worksheet's entire cells contents
Sourcewb1.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=Targetwb1.Sheets("Data").Cells  '<-- need to be Targetwb1 not Targetwb
Sourcewb1.Close (False)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change this line of code,

```
Targetwb1.Worksheets("Data").ClearContents
```

into something like

```
Targetwb1.Sheets("Data").Cells.ClearContents
```

Please let me suggest you to check if the sheet "Data" exists in that workbook.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the first of the lines:
Targetwb1.Sheets("Data").Cells.ClearContents
Sourcewb1.Worksheets(1).Cells.CopyDestination:=Targetwb.Sheets("Data").Cells
Sourcewb1.Close (False)

But still the second is giving the same error. :S